# Remove empty new line at the end of a file

Tags: c, file

I have a file that's storing strings from the user's input (stdin)

However there are 2 situations

If I read it normally, my file will have an empty line at its end due to the newline from the last string the user introduced.

If I remove the `\n` from the input string, the file stores all strings in the same line, which is not wanted.

How can I simply remove that newline from the end of the file?

I can edit and provide some of my code if required.

EDIT: Let's say the last line of a file I already have is "cards"

when the cursor is in front of "cards", if I press the down arrow it doesn't go on to the next line, while in this case it can happen once.

For my code to function perfectly I can't let that happen,

Here's an example of what I have:

```
f=fopen(somefile, "w");
do
{
    fgets(hobby, 50, stdin);
    fprintf(f, "%s", hobby)

} while(strcmp(hobby,"\n") != 0);
```

Comment: How do you read the lines? How do you store the lines? Where do you store the lines? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: It will only appear to have an empty line at its end if you use a weird editor to look at it. Normally the only text file that doesn't end with `\n` is the empty file (containing 0 lines).

Comment: Perhaps you are looking at the file with a text editor and think there is an "extra line" because the cursor is on the next line. It is not so, that is just the typing position of the first character of the next line which does not yet exist.

Comment: The behavior you are describing is that of your text editor. Weather Vane already explained why this happens.  Removing the `'\n'` at the end of the file might not change the observed behavior and **will** have unwanted consequences.

Comment: OK, from your edit, you write an **empty line** at the end of the file, just test for that **before** writing the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newline character<sup>1</sup> at the end of the file is **part** of the last line.  Removing it is possible but makes the last line incomplete, which will break many programs.  For example, concatenating another file at the end of this file will cause the last line to be merged with the first line of the concatenated file.

A Yuri Laguardia commented, if you later reopen this file in append mode to write more lines, the first one added would be concatenated at the end of this last incomplete line. Probably not the intended behavior.

If you do not want the file to contain empty lines, check user input before writing the line into the file:

```
void input_file_contents(FILE *fp) {
    char userinput[80];
    printf("enter file contents:\n");
    while (fgets(userinput, sizeof userinput, stdin)) {
        if (*userinput != '\n') {
            fputs(userinput, fp);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Your code does not test for termination at the right place: you write the empty line **before** the test.  Do not use a `do / while` loop:

```
f = fopen(somefile, "w");
if (f != NULL) {
    /* read lines until end of file or empty line */
    while (fgets(hobby, 50, stdin) != NULL && *hobby != '\n') {
        fputs(hobby, f);
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The newline character is actually a pair of bytes `<CR><LF>` on legacy systems.

Comment: This same undesired behavior would happen if the OP simply decided to open that same file again in append mode to add some more lines, so I completely agree with this answer.